# How to determine type of a BJT by using an ohmmeter?

Tags: transistors, resistance, ohmmeter

Our lecturer in Analog Electronic class mentioned about determining the type of a BJT (whether it is PNP or NPN) by an ohmmeter. I know that in some applications we can determine the type by the multimeter. But how it can be possible to do that. I know ıt has something to do with the internal resistance but I couldn't find any information on internet.

Comment: I would just determine the type by looking up the markings on the part.

Comment: You mean like with the diode test to find out if it's NPN or NPN?

Comment: @Hearth ı know ıt would be more logical to determine its type by looking at the marks but ı am really curious about what kind of physics does it have.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes ı am exactly meaning that. But ı do not know it is possible or not :)

Comment: If you’re only able to measure resistance, you probably can’t without an external circuit to bias it. If you have a regular multimeter, you use the diode test functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from a diode [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85508/bat54.pdf), you could test each PN junction of the BJT as a diode (using the ohmmeter or the diode test function):

[image]

You keep one probe of the multimeter fixed to one pin and test if the other probe measures a resistance to the two other pins (otherwise it shows an open circuit). If this pin connected to the "fixed probe" conducts to the two other pins, it is the base. If the "fixed probe" is the negative one, it is a PNP BJT.

In the image above the "bases" would be the pin 3. The actual "resistance" that your multimeter will measure depends on the test current. Some diode test functions will show the voltage drop in the diode directly polarized.